# Kivy + Numpy @ Android error

Tags: android, python, numpy, kivy, buildozer

When I try to include numpy on the requirements of buildozer I get this message on logcat:
I/python  (26117):  ImportError: cannot import name scimath

And the apps crashes.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Call prebuild_numpy
patching file numpy/core/src/multiarray/numpyos.c
patching file numpy/core/src/private/npy_config.h
Hunk #1 succeeded at 42 with fuzz 2 (offset 1 line).
patching file numpy/testing/__init__.py
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file numpy/testing/__init__.py.rej
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy numpy audiostream" -d "audiotest"

After trying to patch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with updated recipe.sh on python-for-android for numpy.

http://pastebin.com/fB3BtRCn

Get the latest patches from: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/numpy