# How to use Android NDK to compile Numpy as .so?

Tags: android, python, numpy, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Because the Numpy isn't a static library(it contains .py files, .pyc files, .so files, etc), so if I want to import it to my python code which is used in an Android phone(using CLE), I should recompile the library as a .so file. I have found that if I want to use NDK to compile it, I should have an `Application.mk` and an `Android.mk` files. But I don't know how to create these files.

How can I compile the **Numpy** library or anyone could give me a useful website.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pydroid 3 can `pip` load  numpy, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-learn and jupyter.

Comment: @hpaulj Pydroid 3 is an application to run python code. Frankly, I want to build an application, not just run a single python code in an Android mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I should have an Application.mk and an Android.mk files.

This is the older way of Android JNI programming, the current recommended style is to use **CMake** for NDK development.

If you just want a working example and do modification based on it, then you can find one from here: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample

> I should recompile the library as a .so file

In order to recompile, you need its source code for sure. Without source code, you can only try to link those existing **static** libs to form your own `.so` lib.

Comment: Okay I will see it. Numpy is a dynamic library, it contains various of types of files, how can I use CMake to compile it?

Comment: I used pip to install Numpy and Now I could get its folder. Does it contain the source code?

Comment: here is the Numpy source repo on github, https://github.com/numpy/numpy, but whether it can be compiled smoothly on Android is unknown to me.

Comment: Just in case, this link may be helpful to your research: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533680/can-i-run-numpy-or-other-python-packages-on-android and https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1339

Comment: I have tried the source code, the module could be found because it just contains .py files, however an error occurred: cannot find the attribute "Array". I guess the source code also should be compiled, but if compiled, some .so files will interrupt us to import the Numpy Lib.  Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Be aware that all the existing `.so` files that are not originally compiled using **NDK** won't work on Android properly. You need EVERYTHING to be source code and recompile those source using NDK. Usually, this is not a trivial work to do.

Comment: Do you have ways to help me use NDK to compile the Numpy lib? I find it is really difficult to me...

Comment: Just to clarify, you do not *need* to switch from ndk-build. CMake is merely an alternative. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601122/632035

Comment: @DanAlbert, Yes, don't have to