# Kivy - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

I'm trying to create a android aplication with kivy (python) and while simulating with Pycharm everything goes well, but when it comes to the android i simply get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'". I just don't know that's happening and since i'm lost i would like a hand over here! How do i do to import librarys to the apk?

I'm also importing other libraries such as numpy and math

```
# [Library Instance]
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geocoder as gc
import math
```

and these are the lines of my log on android:

```
2021-09-12 18:50:20.546 13055-13106/org.test.myapp I/python:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
2021-09-12 18:50:20.546 13055-13106/org.test.myapp I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Comment: How did you install `numpy`? Install `pandas` the same way.

Comment: @MattDMo The pandas import is first, so maybe they haven't installed either one.

Comment: I did install them using pip, and as i said the code runs perfectly on my pc while simulating the aplication on pycharm that error message only appears on android

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some googling i found this post about the problems when running pandas with kivy on android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534020/6429390

Comment: If you find a duplicate, flag it as such, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: And i want to thank you for that mate. For somereason my vote as useful gave you a -1 and i don't know if that's good or not but you helped me friend!